# How to install PHP pthreads in cpanel?

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, php-extension

I'm trying to use threads in PHP, so I need to install pthreads. It would be nice if EasyApache would have an option for pthreads. But I couldn't find it, so I tried installing it with the pecl command:

```
pecl install pthreads
```

But nothing happened.

Can anyone help me? Has anyone got pthreads working with cpanel?

Comment: Playing with pthreads requires higher level of expertise. Clone the git repository of the project, compile it and enable the shared object in your php.ini. If you are going to use a higher level extension such as that one, do not rely on cpanel and existing (crappy) tools to help you. Learn how to do things properly.

Answer (score 0):

### HOW TO INSTALL IN LINUX SYSTEM'S: C panel With proper rights You can use commands using putty using SSH Shell

1) Download PHP sources and Unpack PHP

2) Download PEAR

```
       wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
       php go-pear.phar
```

3) Download pthreads
Get PECL extension (PECL is a repository for PHP Extensions)

```
          # pecl install pthread-0.4.4
```

4) Unpack pthreads
copy pthread-0.4.4  to  php/ext

```
    (for ./configure allow  add option --enable-pthreads)

    # mv build/php-src-master/ext/pthreads-master    build/php-src-master/ext/pthreads
```

5)  Reconfigure sources

```
       # ./buildconf --force
       # ./configure --help | grep pthreads
```

You should see the appropriate --enable-pthreads option listed as a result, if you do not, then

```
       # rm -rf aclocal.m4
       # rm -rf autom4te.cache/
       # ./buildconf --force
```

6) Build PHP
Compile PHP source code
Add:

```
      # ./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads
```

7) Installing PHP

```
     # make
     # sudo make install
```

8) Update php.ini

```
     Add in php.ini
     extension=pthreads.so
     Include_path = “/usr/local/lib/php”
```

9) Check Modules
         php -m (check pthread loaded)

10) Test Thread Class
        # php SimpleTest.php

> And specially if you have not WHM or any root access then best way is
>   to ask your host provider to install any package for you, If it is not
>   harmful for server or consume resources then they will surly install
>   it for you.

Check PHP PEAR Packages  from your Control panel. and search for available packages.
PHP Extension(s) and Application(s) 
Available for Installation